# Disable an option in jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the following jquery to create an autocomplete menu from the values returned by a php script.

These are the values returned by PHP.

```
["Site 4","Site 2","Site 1","*************","Site 6","Site 7","Site 0"]
```

and this is my jquery for the autocomplete:

```
$( '#site' ).autocomplete({
    source: 'siteCheck.php',
    autoFocus: true, 
    minLength: 1,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        $('#site').val(ui);
    }
});
```

This returns the correct results to screen and shows the `*************` option. However I'd like to make that option **BOLD** and stop it being selected from the list.

Is that possible? I have tried to use jquery to disable the select option but that doesn't seem to do anything.

This isn't a duplicate of the other ticket, they are asking how to disable entries after a specific number of results show.. I want to disable ONE specific entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've modified [one the examples](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) on jQuery's official site. It should be simple enough to adapt it for your data.

Here's how it works:

1. The property `disabled` in data array (`projects`) tells the custom rendering logic whether or not an option is disabled.
2. I have customized the renderer to set a class `ui-state-disabled` on the option if the element has `disabled` set to `true`. It also helps set the `background-color` to gray and `font-weight` to bold.
3. Then on the `focus` event handler, you `return false` if the item is disabled. This prevents jQuery from populating the item into the input as you navigate down.
4. Finally, on the `select` handler, again, you prevent the value from being selected based on the value of `disabled` property.

```js
var projects = [{
    value: "jquery",
    label: "jQuery",
    desc: "the write less, do more, JavaScript library",
    icon: "jquery_32x32.png",
    disabled: false
  },
  {
    value: "jquery-ui",
    label: "jQuery UI",
    desc: "the official user interface library for jQuery",
    icon: "jqueryui_32x32.png",
    disabled: true
  },
  {
    value: "sizzlejs",
    label: "Sizzle JS",
    desc: "a pure-JavaScript CSS selector engine",
    icon: "sizzlejs_32x32.png",
    disabled: false
  }
];


$("#project").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: projects,
    focus: function(event, ui) {
      if(ui.item.disabled) {
        console.log("Preventing focus.");
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      if(!ui.item.disabled) {
        $("#project").val(ui.item.label);
      } else {
        console.log("Preventing selection.");
      }
      return false;
    }
  })
  .autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
      .append("<div class='"+(item.disabled ? 'ui-state-disabled' : '')+"'>" + item.label + "<br>" + item.desc + "</div>")
      .appendTo(ul);
  };
```

```css
.ui-menu-item-wrapper.ui-state-disabled {
  background-color: #aaa;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<input id="project">
```